# Multiple hits in on page in MTurk

Tags: text, twitter, classification, mechanicalturk

In Mturk, we want to show a set of tweets, e.g., 20 tweets, in boxes in one page. Then, Workers click JUST on the tweets (boxes) that are relevant to a specific concept like "entrepreneurship". For example for 3 tweets:

Tweet 1: Money and supporting customers are essential for a business

Tweet 2: I like tennis

Tweet 3: I spend my invest for buying my home.

Tweets should be shown in boxes and Workers should just click on Tweet 1 (instead of clicking on Yes or No buttons) and MTurk returns the results in a file (like csv format) in this way:

Yes (or 1)

No (or 0)

No (or 0)

We want to show multiple tweets (multiple hits) in one page.

How can we create a code so that for a batch of tweets, MTurk reads 20 tweets from the batch and puts them in their place for the Workers?
Is there such design? If yes, would you please guide me how I can do it? With many thanks. Jafar

Answer (score 1):

All 20 tweets would be required to be part of the same HIT. There's no way to create one HIT per tweet, then have Mechanical Turk display 20 of them as one task for a worker to complete.

Comment: We should use and write 20 variables in the HTML code so that MTurk system reads 20 tweets together from the batch for each page, .i.e. ${tweet1}, ${tweet2}, ...,${tweet20}. Is there any way for creating this automatically?